# How to push a split results into array PL SQL and return array data with a ref cursor

Tags: arrays, oracle, plsql, cursor

I am trying to push a split result into an array, but I do not know how to do it. Here is my stored procedure:

```
   CODE_KZ_i NVARCHAR2 (4000):='';
   FTKZ NVARCHAR2 (4000):='';

   TYPE namesarray IS TABLE OF NVARCHAR2(4000);
   FTarray namesarray:=namesarray();
   i NUMBER;
```

begin

```
    FOR FTKZ IN ( SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (KZ,'[^;]+', 1,LEVEL)  TXT  FROM DUAL 
                  CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR (KZ,'[^;]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL)

    LOOP

    FTarray.extend;

    IF CONTA = 0 THEN CODE_KZ:=FTKZ.TXT;
    ELSE 
    CODE_KZ:= FTKZ.TXT;

    END IF;

    FTarray(i):= CODE_KZ;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('FT:'|| FTarray(i));
    i:=i+1;
    CONTA:=CONTA+1;
```

My goal is to push the result of FTKZ.TXT into FTarray. Does anyone can help me please?

Next step is to return array's data in a sys_refcursor. I get some code in input named KZ and I have to return another code, linked to kz which is in this table: SG_AN_FT

```
    open p_cur_result for
    SELECT DISTINCT FT.CODE as FT INTO P_RESULT FROM SG_AN_FT FT 
          INNER JOIN SG_BOM_PIVOT_PN_KZ BOM
          ON FT.ID = BOM.ID_FT
          INNER JOIN SG_AN_KZ K
          ON K.ID = BOM.ID_KZ
          WHERE K.CODE in (SELECT * FROM TABLE(cast(FTarray as FT));

    Errore(317,60): PL/SQL: ORA-00902: tipo di dati non valido
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: What is you if/else for - you do the same either way? Why do you have `i` and `conta` (which isn't declared)? What is `KZ`?. What exactly are you struggling with - fixing errors in the current code - if so what errors do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You loop code seems pretty close; adding a definition and dummy value for KZ and cleaning up other variables you can do:

```
declare
  -- made up as not shown in the question
  KZ NVARCHAR2 (4000) := 'A;B;C;D';

  CODE_KZ NVARCHAR2 (4000);

  TYPE namesarray IS TABLE OF NVARCHAR2(4000);
  FTarray namesarray:=namesarray();
  CONTA NUMBER := 1;
begin
  FOR FTKZ IN ( SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (KZ,'[^;]+', 1,LEVEL)  TXT  FROM DUAL 
                CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR (KZ,'[^;]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL)
  LOOP
    FTarray.extend;

    -- redundant as both branches do the same thing; also can't be zero
    IF CONTA = 0 THEN
      CODE_KZ:=FTKZ.TXT;
    ELSE 
      CODE_KZ:= FTKZ.TXT;
    END IF;

    FTarray(CONTA):= CODE_KZ;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('FT:'|| FTarray(CONTA));
    CONTA:=CONTA+1;
  END LOOP;
end;
/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

FT:A
FT:B
FT:C
FT:D
```

Your `IF CONTA = 0` checks suggests you were starting your loop with index zero, which would get `ORA-06532: Subscript outside of limit` as collections are indexed from one not zero. That check seems redundant anyway as you assign the same value to the variable in both branches, so you can just assign `FTKZ.TXT` directly to the newly-extended array element. You don't really need `CONTA` or `CODE_KZ` at all:

```
declare
  -- made up as not shown in the question
  KZ NVARCHAR2 (4000) := 'A;B;C;D';

  TYPE namesarray IS TABLE OF NVARCHAR2(4000);
  FTarray namesarray:=namesarray();
begin
  FOR FTKZ IN ( SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (KZ,'[^;]+', 1,LEVEL)  TXT  FROM DUAL 
                CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR (KZ,'[^;]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL)
  LOOP
    FTarray.extend;
    FTarray(FTArray.count) := FTKZ.TXT;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('FT:'|| FTarray(FTArray.count));
  END LOOP;
end;
/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

FT:A
FT:B
FT:C
FT:D
```

But you also don't need to use a loop, [you can use `bulk collect` to populate your collection in one go](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/tuning.htm#LNPLS891):

```
declare
  -- made up as not shown in the question
  KZ NVARCHAR2 (4000) := 'A;B;C;D';

  TYPE namesarray IS TABLE OF NVARCHAR2(4000);
  FTarray namesarray:=namesarray();
begin
  SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (KZ,'[^;]+', 1,LEVEL) TXT
  BULK COLLECT INTO FTarray
  FROM DUAL 
  CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR (KZ,'[^;]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL;

  FOR i IN 1..FTarray.count LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('FT:' || FTarray(i));
  END LOOP;
end;
/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

FT:A
FT:B
FT:C
FT:D
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It Is exactly what I was trying to understand. The process run correclty this way. I know what to do now.Next time I will try to make the issue clearer.